# Clojure - map with unbound function

Tags: clojure

I'm following a Clojure tutorial in [Try Clojure](http://www.tryclj.com/), where we are introduced to defining our functions -

```
(defn square [x] (* x x))
```

Then apply it to a list of numbers:

```
(map square [1 2 3 4])
```

Which promptly prints out an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to call unbound fn: #'sandbox14750/square`

When I try to map for example function `inc`, that works fine - what's the difference between the built-in function `inc` and my `square`?

Comment: I just tried this in Try Clojure and it worked. A couple of days ago I was using Try Clojure and it lost the vars I had def-ed. It was several minutes between when I def-ed them and when I referenced, so I chocked it up to the sandboxing reclaiming resources.

Comment: When I first tried in TryClojure, it worked well. I tried again after I noticed your comment on my answer, I had the same problem. However, it works now. I'm not sure what happened. Anyway, your code is OK. I suspect that the site had some internal problem.

Comment: ok - I'll really try in real clojure REPL then.

Comment: can you try that again? I seem to recall try-clj sometimes randomly resetting the sandbox, which can lead to old definitions disappearing

Comment: "the interpreter deletes the data that you enter if you define too many things, or after 15 minutes"

Comment: really looks like a bug of the online interpreter - i can't use defined functions immediately :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some trouble the first time I tried to run it though after refreshing the page it went fine.

```
Give me some Clojure:
> (defn square [x] (* x x))
#'sandbox6361/square
> (square 4)
16
> (map square [1 2 3 4])
(1 4 9 16)
```

If you want to make sure your functions are still available when you need them you can store your functions in locals instead of vars like so:

```
> (let [square (fn [x] (* x x))] (map square [1 2 3 4]))
(1 4 9 16)
>
```

many sandbpxed environments like Clojurebot on #clojure don't let you define arbitrary state so it's worth knowing that functions can be stored in many ways, not just in vars.